# How to preserve a child element's bind functions in jQuery/javascript

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, hover, event-bubbling

I have some  tags that I want to bind to a function within jQuery's datepicker. However, jQuery automatically binds another function to the parent (`.ui-datepicker-inline`) div's `mouseover` and `mouseout` events.

I want to override this function in some cases, but when some other event occurs, revert back to default functioning. I tried binding `mouseover` to it's parent div (`hasDatepicker`) and this worked fine. However when I unbind the parent, the child's old bind function stops working as well. Why is this? Is there any way to avoid that? I don't care if the child keeps it's bind function, as long as the parent's bind does it's thing afterward. I also don't want to lose the child functionality when I unbind the parent.

I have a jQuery element `datePicker` which is the element that has the original bind (`.ui-datepicker-inline`) as far as I can tell from the jQuery UI code.

```
// This binds my function, occurring after datePicker's bound function,
// and works fine.
datePicker.parent().bind('mouseover', hoverWeek) // hoverWeek is a function(event)

/* ... */

// This unbind's datePicker as well as datePicker.parent()
datePicker.parent().unbind('mouseover');
```

Can I save the bound function and put it back when I need it? I shouldn't think I'd have to, but if I did, how would I even go about doing that? Can I just say `datePicker.bind('mouseover')` to get the function bound to it?

**[Update]**
There were a few issues: Mainly I had some conflicting code, but there were also some issues with the [bubbling effect](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html). The solutions listed below are both good, and for future reference, here is another solution that works: http://jsfiddle.net/redEvo/7QpDx/

Comment: What does `hoverWeek()` do? Could that be interfering with the `mouseover`? Like you, I made a fiddle and it works fine!

Comment: well instead of highlighting the day you're hovering over, it highlights the entire week (similar to [this](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerSelectWeek.html), but not close enough that I can use that). If I put an event handler on the days, it highlights the week then bubbles out and only highlights the day (too fast for the naked eye to see). If I put it on the parent, the original never seems to happen (when I try to go back to default mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass just your function to the unbind call:

```
datePicker.parent().unbind('mouseover', hoverWeek);
```

Comment: That's what I thought too but it doesn't seem to be working. I made a jsFiddle but of course it works fine there. There must be something else I'm missing -- the jQuery UI code is somewhat complex. I think ideally I would be able to only bind the `.ui-datepicker-calendar` class but it's ancestor's bind occurs after mine, overriding it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure how much else I can do without more of the code. It seems to work in [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m2PgT) for me. I even implemented a `hoverWeek()` although you may be doing more than in my version.

I am using [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) in a slightly different way using namespaced events:

```
datePicker.bind('mouseover.myEvent', hoverWeek);
```